# security for http headers

Tags: security, http, http-headers, escaping, base64

We'd like to double-check our http headers for security before we send them out. Obviously we can't allow '\r' or '\n' to appear, as that would allow content injection.

I see just two options here:

1. Truncate the value at the newline character.
2. Strip the invalid character from the header value.

Also, from reading [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2), it seems that only ascii-printable characters are valid for http header values Should also I follow the same policy for the other 154 possible invalid bytes?

Or, is there any authoritative prior art on this subject?

Answer (score 4):

This attack is called "header splitting" or ["response splitting"](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting).

That OWASP link points out that removing CRLF is not sufficient.  `\n` can be just as dangerous.

> To mount a successful exploit, the application must allow input that contains CR (carriage return, also given by 0x0D or \r) and LF (line feed, also given by 0x0A or \n)characters into the header.

(I do not know why OWASP (and other pages) list `\n` as a vulnerability or whether that only applies to query fragments pre-decode.)

Serving a 500 on any attempt to set a header that contains a character not allowed by the spec in a header key or value is perfectly reasonable, and will allow you to identify offensive requests in your logs.  Failing fast when you know your filters are failing is a fine policy.

If the language you're working in allows it, you could wrap your HTTP response object in one that raises an exception when a bad header is seen, or you could change the response object to enter an invalid state, set the response code to 500, and close the response body stream.

EDIT:

> Should I strip non-ASCII inputs?

I prefer to do that kind of normalization in the layer that receives trusted input unless, as in the case of entity-escaping to convert plain-text to HTML escaping, there is a clear type conversion.  If it's a type conversion, I do it when the output type is required, but if it is not a type-conversion, I do it as early as possible so that all consumers of data of that type see a consistent value.  I find this approach makes debugging and documentation easier since layers below input handling never have to worry about unnormalized inputs.

When implementing the HTTP response wrapper, I would make it fail on *all* non-ascii characters (including non-ASCII newlines like U+85, U+2028, U+2029) and then make sure my application tests include a test for each third-party URL input to makes sure that any `Location` headers are properly %-encoded before the Location reaches `setHeader`, and similarly for other inputs that might reach the request headers.

If your cookies include things like a user-id or email address, I would make sure the dummy accounts for tests include a dummy account with a user-id or email address containing a non-ASCII letter.

Comment: Should we strip non-ascii-printable characters?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, but I'm not following this particularly well. You seem to recommend both stripping all non-ascii characters, but make sure that non-ascii cookies function. It seems like one would preclude the other.

Comment: About your hypothetical request wrapper: Do you know of any library that functions this way? If i'm understanding correctly, you would perform these checks during a setHeader method, in order to fail as early as possible.

Comment: @bukzor, Lots of libraries throw `IllegalArgumentException`, libraries like `java.nio` throw `IllegalStateException` when moved into an inconsistent state by an illegal mark, guava collection builders fail-fast with runtime exceptions when the resulting object could not be built due to invalid members or duplicate keys, java's [fail-fast iterators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) which throw `ConcurrentModificationException` when they realize that they have been moved into an inconsistent state from which they cannot recover.

Comment: @bukzor, I believe `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` also both move into an invalid state when a failure to externalize/deserialize means that there is a high likelihood that subsequent operations would be operating on a stream that was only partially constructed/consumed.

Answer (score 3):

The simple removal of new lines `\n` will prevent [HTTP Response Splitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_splitting).  Even though a CRLF is used as a delimiter in the RFC,  the new line alone is recognized by all browsers.

You still have to worry about user content within a `set-cookie` or `content-type`.  Attributes within these elements are delimited using a `;`,  it maybe possible for an attacker to change the content type to UTF-7 and bypass your XSS protection for IE users (and only IE users).  It may also be possible for an attacker to create a new cookie,  which introduces the possibility of Session Fixation.

Comment: Can you expand the UTF7-related XSS more, or give a reference?

Comment: @Rook, I believe if you control the `Content-type` header, you can do UTF-7 attacks on browsers besides IE.  It is only IE that will guess UTF-7 when no encoding is specified, but other browsers will should still respect a UTF-7 header.  ha.ckers.org includes "Netscape 8.1 in IE rendering engine mode" among the browsers that auto-detect and implies strongly that other browsers respect the header.

Comment: @bukzor, see the section titled "UTF-7 encoding" in the [cheat sheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html): `<HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-7"> </HEAD>+ADw-SCRIPT+AD4-alert('XSS');+ADw-/SCRIPT+AD4-`

Comment: @Mike Samuel  Great,  have you tried to execute that snip of code on firefox or chrome?  UTF-7 is for SMTP,  not HTTP,  IE is the only one that supports it,  and they dropped UTF-7 content sniffing in IE9.  The xss cheat sheet is like 5 years old,  its almost useless.

Comment: @Rook.  I haven't tried it on recent builds of non-MS browsers.  I agree about purpose of UTF-7.  My understanding was that browsers at some point used standard libraries of byte[]->UTF-16[] decodings and UTF-7 was available in many of these libraries.  If newer browsers are more skeptical of encodings, wonderful, but those of us working on frameworks need to support app-developers who want to support IE 6 and older versions of Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Non-ASCII characters are allowed in header fields, although the spec doesn't really clearly say what they mean; so it's up to sender and recipient to agree on their semantics.

What made you think otherwise?

Comment: Headers are defined as TEXT, and TEXT is "any OCTET except CTLs, but including LWS". CTLs are "(octets 0 - 31) and DEL (127)". This seems to allow octects > 127, but I doubt that was intended.

Comment: I see some allowance for non-iso-8859-1 encodings via "encoded words", but it goes on to say that "only printable and white space character data should be encoded using this scheme", in which case I'd rather just use ascii.

Comment: bukzor: I think it was intended, and I know it's occasionally used.

It's also needed that intermediates let all 8 bits pass, otherwise it won't be possible to use UTF-8 as header field encoding some time in the future.

Comment: I'd think that utf8 is already out, since octets 0-31 and 127 are explicitly disallowed.

Comment: bukzor: no that just means you can't have CTLs or DEL. That doesn't affect the remainder of the character repertoire.

Comment: I had assumed that utf8 would use those bytes, but I wrote a small script and found that I was wrong. Thanks. http://pastebin.com/Q9hgRDnG

Comment: [RFC7230](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2) specifies that header field content may only be ASCII text. Other characters are obsolete (obs-text).

Comment: @DagHøidahl "obsolete" doesn't mean illegal.

Comment: @JulianReschke Agreed, it just means obsolete. But by classifying something as obsolete, the latest spec clearly advises against using it. So I think this answer should clarify that.